# Inserting existing value into a table, not creating new one

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I have a student_id that already exists in student table, so I am trying to insert that student into a enrollment table and not create a new one, but the problem is these two tables have different columns and I am not sure what to put under the section_id column because section_id is number and if I choose anything from a student table into a select statement I get an error...

I usually get the error "integrity constraint violated - parent key not found".

I put the question mark where the problem is here...How could I solve this ???

[image]

this is what I have

```
INSERT INTO ENROLLMENT(STUDENT_ID,SECTION_ID,ENROLL_DATE, FINAL_GRADE, CREATED_BY ,CREATED_DATE ,MODIFIED_BY ,MODIFIED_DATE )
SELECT STUDENT_ID, ???? ,sysdate,NULL,'john',sysdate,'john',sysdate
FROM STUDENT
WHERE STUDENT_ID = 300;
```

Comment: It's **yours** schema. **You** should know what `section_id` is... It is a foreign key, so it links `enrollment` table values with another table.

Comment: ok , I updated the schema, so how could I tell what section_id is when the student is not enrolled yet in the enrollemnet table but exists in student table ??

Comment: You need to determine the correct SECTION_ID which should exist in the SECTION table. Talk to someone who understands your data model.

Comment: if student_id 300 existed in any other table I wouldn't ask this question, and yes I have selected to see if this student_id exits in every single table, but gives me no results...

Comment: For "integrity constraint violated - parent key not found" error you need to find parent child (primary key - foreign key) relationship. Make sure data is present in parent table before isnerting into child thats what above posts are suggesting

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
 
INSERT INTO ENROLLMENT(STUDENT_ID,SECTION_ID,ENROLL_DATE, FINAL_GRADE, CREATED_BY ,CREATED_DATE                         ,MODIFIED_BY ,MODIFIED_DATE )
SELECT STUDENT_ID, ???? (SECTION.SECTION_ID value) ,sysdate,NULL,'john',sysdate,'john',sysdate
FROM STUDENT
WHERE STUDENT_ID = 300;
```

Look data in table SECTION. If there is no rows then insert one. Take value from field SECTION_ID and put it instead of ???? ( like 100). Also must be inserted row with STUDENT_ID = 300 in table STUDENT, for this case.